# Prove $\{a_n\}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Suppose $a_1,a_2>0$ and
> $a_{n+2}=2+\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}^2}+\dfrac{1}{a_n^2}(n\ge 1)$. Prove
> $\{a_n\}$ converges.

First, we may show $\{a_n\}$ is bounded for $n\ge 3$, since $$2 \le a_{n+2}\le 2+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}=\frac{5}{2},~~~~~~ \forall n \ge 1.$$

But how to go on?

Comment: As a side comment, if the sequence converges, it must converge to the only real root of $l^3-2l^2-2$, which is approximately 2.359.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach: Let $L \approx 2.3593$ be the unique solution of $L = 2 + 2/L^2$ in the interval $[2, 2.5]$, and $b_n = a_n - L$. We want to show that $b_n \to 0$.

The recursion formula becomes
$$
 b_{n+2} = \frac{1}{(L+b_{n+1})^2} + \frac{1}{(L+b_{n})^2} - \frac{2}{L^2} \, .
$$

We estimate
$$
 \left| \frac{1}{(L+b_{n})^2} - \frac{1}{L^2}\right| = \frac{|b_n|(2L+b_n)}{L^2(L+b_n)^2} \le \frac{5}{16} |b_n|
$$
for $n \ge 3$, so that
$$
|b_{n+2} | \le \frac{5}{16} (|b_{n+1}| + |b_n|) \, . 
$$
Then
$$
 2 |b_{n+2} | + |b_{n+1} | \le \frac{13}{8}|b_{n+1} | + \frac{5}{8}|b_{n}|
\le \frac{13}{16} \left(2 |b_{n+1} | + |b_{n} | \right) \, .
$$
This shows that $2 |b_{n+1} | + |b_{n} |$ decreases geometrically to zero. It follows that $b_n \to 0$, as desired.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $2<a_n<3$ for $n\ge5$. Since, for $n\ge5$,
\begin{eqnarray} 
&&|a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}|\\
&=&\bigg|\frac{1}{a_{n+2}^2}-\frac{1}{a_{n}^2}\bigg|=\frac{(a_{n+2}+a_{n})|a_{n+2}-a_{n}|}{a_{n+2}^2a_{n}^2}\\
&\le&\frac{6}{2^2\cdot 2^2}|a_{n+2}-a_{n}|\le\frac12|a_{n+2}-a_{n}|\\
&\le&\cdots\le\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}|a_5-a_3|
\end{eqnarray}
we conclude that $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$ exists.

Comment: @Sil Yes, In general it will hold for $n \ge 5$. Proof:
forall $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $a_n > 0 \Rightarrow a_{n+2} > 2 \Rightarrow a_{n+4} < 5/2 < 3$

Comment: Thanks for pointing $a_n\in(2,3)$ for $n\ge 5$.

Comment: You have shown that $|a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}| \le \frac 12 |a_{n+2}-a_{n}|$, but how exactly do you continue? You cannot apply the same estimate again because on the RHS the indices differ by $2$.

Comment: @MartinR You can use triangle inequality. But that is a good point, as then you must use a constant $< \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Kaind: Yes, that is what cybershiptrooper did with $6/16$.

Comment: @Kaind try looking up leaves of a binary tree. Maybe it would help with your query. It is always less than $2^n$. So a constant less than should suffice (I think)

Comment: @cybershiptrooper I actually missed that you bounded by $2^n$ - it's almost correct, except that in the tree, the leaves won't have $|a_3 - a_1|$, some could have $|a_4 - a_2|$, and so on. But yes, this case should work out easily.

Comment: @Kaind Yes, that was the issue arising due to different parities. I have edited my answer to include it. Please do check for completeness now.

Comment: Btw isn't this answer still wrong? @admins/someone?

Comment: @cybershiptrooper Your answer is correct. But this answer is still wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not so sure about this one, but here's my attempt-

\begin{align}
\lVert a_{n+1}-a_n  \rVert &= \left\lVert \frac{1}{a_n^2}-\frac{1}{a_{n-2}^2}  \right\rVert\\
&\leq \frac{ \lVert {a_{n-2}^2}-a_n^2   \rVert }{16} \\
&= \frac{ \lVert {a_{n-2}+a_{n}} \rVert \lVert {a_{n-2}-a_{n}}   \rVert }{16} \\
&\leq \frac{6}{16} \lVert {a_{n-2}-a_{n}} \rVert \\
&=\frac{6}{16} \left\lVert \frac{1}{a_{n-3}^2} + \frac{1}{a_{n-4}^2} - \frac{1}{a_{n-1}^2} - \frac{1}{a_{n-2}^2} \right\rVert \\
&=\frac{6}{16} \left\lVert \left(\frac{1}{a_{n-3}^2} - \frac{1}{a_{n-1}^2}\right)  + \left(\frac{1}{a_{n-4}^2} - \frac{1}{a_{n-2}^2}\right) \right\rVert \\
&\leq \frac{6}{16} \cdot \frac{6}{16} \lVert (a_{n-1}-a_{n-3})+(a_{n-2}-a_{n-4})   \rVert\\
&\ \ \vdots \\
&\leq \left(\frac{6}{16}\right)^n max(|| a_4-a_2 ||,\lVert a_3-a_1||)2^n  \\
&=\left(\frac{12}{16}\right)^n max(|| a_4-a_2 ||,\lVert a_3-a_1||)
\end{align}

(Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBBqe.jpg )

Does this seem correct? I tried using Cauchy's convergence test and the fact that the tail lies between 2 and 3. If not, I hope it provides at least some clue to the correct path. The last step is a result of the observation that each term of $a_k - a_{k-2}$ should produce two similar terms(as seen while expanding), whose index decreases linearly.

Edit: I have added the term $max(|| a_4-a_2 ||,\lVert a_3-a_1||)$ instead of the original single term to take care of the parity issue.

Comment: I took the liberty and typeset it into MathJax (see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ). Please check in case I made any mistake.

Comment: @cybershiptrooper Why the norms? It is a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: @Kaind the first term gives rise to two terms- one with an index 'shorter'(call this the first kind) and the other with two short. Now, these will generate two and two each, that is, four such terms. Anyways, the order will be commanded by the first kind. Assuming all of them are first kind, wouldn't we get $2^n$ now(but we can't replace it completely, which was my doubt.. a workaround is to include two different terms based on parity)? I didn't really get your question.. Perhaps you could explain it in other words? Try it out for a small n(5-6). I ended up with way less than $2^n$ terms..

Comment: @PierreCarre Sorry.. a force of habit from a recent course.. But if is it mathematically wrong, please do replace it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use **fixed point iteration**s.

**Observe**:
Substituting $x_n > 2$ gives us a upper bound on $x_{n}$ ($n \geq 3$). And substituting this upper bound back, gives us a 'closer' lower bound. And so on. I hope to show that these lower and upper bounds converge, which effectively then says that $x_n$ must converge to that point eventually.

Define $g(x) := 2(1 + \frac{1}{x^2})$. Then the sequence we consider is $t_{n+1} = g(t_n)$. Using the fixed point iteration theorem, we have

(1) $t \in [2,3] \Rightarrow g(t) \in [2,3]$, and $g$ is continuous.

(2) $|g'(t)| = \frac{4}{t^3} < 1$

Hence $\exists \alpha \in (2,3)$ s.t. $\forall t_0, \; \in (2,3)$ $ t_n =  g^{(n)}(t_0) \rightarrow \alpha$.

**Claim 1**: Let $N_0, t > 0$.

1. $(\forall n \geq N_0, \; x_n > t) \Rightarrow (\forall n \geq N_0 + 2, \; x_n < g(t))$.
2. $(\forall n \geq N_0, \; x_n < t) \Rightarrow (\forall n \geq N_0 + 2, \; x_n > g(t))$

**Proof**. Trivial. $\square$

**Claim 2**: $\forall n \geq 5, \; x_n \in (2,3)$.

**Proof**. $(\forall n > 0, \; x_n > 0) \Rightarrow (\forall n > 0, \; x_{n+2} > 2) \Rightarrow (\forall n > 0, \; x_{n+4} < \frac{5}{2} < 3)$ $\square$

**Claim 3.** Let $S = \lim \sup x_n$ and $I = \lim \inf x_n$. Then
$S \leq \alpha \land I \geq \alpha$.

**Proof**. Fix $t \in \mathbb{N}$. As $g^{(n)}(x_5) \rightarrow \alpha$, $\exists N'$ s.t. $n \geq \max(N', t) \Rightarrow g^{(n)}(x_5) \in (\alpha - \frac{1}{t}, \alpha + \frac{1}{t})$.

Then by Claim 1 and 2, $\sup_{m \geq (5 + 2\max(t,N')) } x_m \le \alpha + \frac{1}{t} \Rightarrow \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{m \geq (5 + 2\max(t,N')) } x_m \le \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} (\alpha + \frac{1}{t}) \Rightarrow S \le \alpha$.

Similarly, show $I \ge \alpha$. $\square$

**Corollary**. Thus $\lim_n x_n = S = I = \alpha$.

**Proof.** Trivial. $\square$

**Edit 2.** Thanks to @Martin R, to help me formalize the proof.

**Edit 1.** As @NN2's answer notes, this is actually an attracting stable fixed point, which I've proved using fixed point iterations. (Alternatively, you could just use the theorem (which I didn't know) - check NN2's answer).

Comment: Read the proof carefully. The function $g(x)$ is the sequence of alternating upper and lower bounds for the the sequence $x_n$. Nowhere have I assumed $x_n$ is converging.

Comment: Ok, you are right.

Comment: I think that $x_n > t \iff x_{n+2} < g(t)$ requires some justification, since $x_{n+2}$ depends on $x_n$ *and* $x_{n+1}$.

Comment: @MartinR What I meant was:
If for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_n > t$ then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_{n+2} < g(t)$. I'll edit after a while - in a meeting now.

Comment: I would argue as follows: If $S$ and $I$ are the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of the sequence then $S \le g(I)$ and $I \ge g(S)$. It follows that $S \le g(g(S))$ and $I \ge g(g(I))$, which implies that both $S$ and $I$ are equal to the fixed point of $g$.

Comment: @MartinR I formalized the proof. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote $f(x) = 2+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}$ and $l$ is the real root of the equation $$f(x)=x$$
(this is a cubic equation which has only $1$ real root and this rootcan be obtained from the [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula))

We have $l \approx 2.55$

Calculate the derivarive of $f(x)$ and notice that [if $|f'(l)|<1$ then the fixed point $l$ is stable and an attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory#Maps). Indeed, we have

$$f'(x) = -\frac{2}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

and  $$|f'(l)| \approx 0.27 <1$$

Hence, according to the stability theory, the sequence converges to $l$. Q.E.D

Comment: How do you apply the fixed point iteration for  $f(x) = 2+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}$ to the recursion $a_{n+2}=2+\frac{1}{a_{n+1}^2}+\frac{1}{a_n^2}$?